# An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

Tags: entity-framework

I want to bind gridview through  entity framework but it throws error
like-

> An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name Entity Framwrok

Here is my method.

```
public void UserList(GridView grdUserList)
{
    using (TreDbEntities context = new TreDbEntities())
    {

        var query =( from m in context.aspnet_Membership
                    from u in context.aspnet_Users
                    join usr in context.Users
                    on new { m.UserId, u.UserId } 
                    equals new { usr.MembershipUserID, usr.UserId }
                    into UserDetails
                    from usr in UserDetails
                    select new { 
                       CreationDate = m.CreateDate,
                       email = m.Email,
                       UserName = u.LoweredUserName,
                       Name = usr.FirstName + usr.LastNameLastName,
                       Active=usr.IsActive
                    }).ToList();
    }
}
```

It shows error here. usr.UserId.

Answer (score 32):

The direct issue is in the anonymous type `new { m.UserId, u.UserId }`: the same name twice. You can fix that by giving explicit property names, for example: `new { u1 = m.UserId, u2 = u.UserId }`.

But then the next issue will be that both anonymous types that define the join will not have the same property names, so the final fix is this:

```
public void UserList(GridView grdUserList)
{
    using (TreDbEntities context = new TreDbEntities())
    {
        var query =( from m in context.aspnet_Membership
                    from u in context.aspnet_Users
                    join usr in context.Users
                    on new { u1 = m.UserId, u2 = u.UserId } 
                    equals new { u1 = usr.MembershipUserID, u2 = usr.UserId }
                    into UserDetails
                    from usr in UserDetails
                    select new { CreationDate = m.CreateDate,
                                 email = m.Email,
                                 UserName = u.LoweredUserName,
                                 Name = usr.FirstName + " " + usr.LastName,
                                 Active = usr.IsActive
                               }
                   ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

@Gert answer is correct. Just want to show simpler solution - give name only to first UserId property:

```
on new { MembershipUserID = m.UserId, u.UserId }
```

Comment: Possible. The only thing is imo it makes the code less self-explanatory because the first UserId may have nothing to do with `MembershipUserID`. Using two "anonymous" names shows that the properties are just placeholders.

Comment: @GertArnold first use id has something to do with membership :) it is id from aspnet_Membership table. Also I think `u1` is much less self-explanatory, than `MembershipUserID`. I upvoted your answer thus it is also completely correct and it explains reason of error :)

Comment: Sure, no worries at all! It's just that I like my code to show that identical property names are enforced. Maybe just a matter of taste.