# How I give result of inner join to gridview datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have 2 tables.

```
Branches (BranchId,Name, Area)
Managers (ManagerId,Name,BranchId)
```

I want when I click on Branches branch data will show with manager name. I use `gridview` to show data.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="gvBranches">
</asp:GridView>
```

First of all I write LINQ Query.

```
CDDataContext dc = new CDDataContext();
var data = (from branch in dc.Branches
            join manager in dc.Managers
            on branch.BranchId equals manager.BranchId
            select branch).ToList();
gvBranches.DataSource = data;
gvBranches.DataBind();
```

It just display the record of branch. like `BranchId Name Area`

Then I write Stored Procedure.

Stored Procedure:

```
create procedure sp_AllBranches
As
Begin
return  Select b.BranchId, b.Name, b.Area, m.Name
        from Branches as b, Managers as m
        where b.BranchId=m.BranchId
End
```

Code:

```
CDDataContext dc = new CDDataContext();
var data = dc.sp_AllBranches();
gvBranches.DataSource = data;
gvBranches.DataBind();
```

It display nothing. Please help.

Comment: You need to import the stored procedure as a `Function`. Check this post for complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework

Comment: @user2946329 I read above link, I didn't use Entity framework and there is no option to import Stored Procedure as a Functions. Simply I just want to fill `GridView` with results that come from two tables. Also I execute stored procedure it returns 0.

Comment: I find another article on stackoverflow, it solves my problem with LINQ query. `CDDataContext dc = new CDDataContext();
            var data = from branch in dc.Branches
                         join manager in dc.Managers
                          on branch.BranchId equals manager.BranchId
                            select new{
                            branch.BranchId, BranchName = branch.Name, branch.Area, ManagerName = manager.Name
        }   ;
            gvBranches.DataSource = data;
            gvBranches.DataBind();
        }`

Comment: Here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978395/an-anonymous-type-cannot-have-multiple-properties-with-the-same-name/18983808#18983808)

Comment: If there is a relationship between branch and manager there should be a foreign key in you database and this should be represented by your model. So Manager should have a Branch property and Branch a Managers property. You shouldn't need to join two entities with a relationship.