# EF - anonymous type cannot have multiples...

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method with which is the following:

```
 using (ubmmsEntities db = new ubmmsEntities())
        {
            var result = (from l in db.log_documents
                          join t in db.teams on l.op_user_team equals t.id
                          where l.tracking_id == trackingID
                          select new { l.op_code, l.op_date, l.op_description, l.op_refer_code, l.op_refer_comments, t.team_name, l.id });
            return result.
```

Now I have to add another column it, and in simple SQL all I would need is to add two more inner joins, but I am quite lost how to do it in EF a the below results a error under t2.team_name "An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name".

```
using (ubmmsEntities db = new ubmmsEntities())
        {
            var result = (from l in db.log_documents
                          join t in db.teams on l.op_user_team equals t.id
                          join r in db.refers_codes on l.op_refer_code equals r.code
                          join t2 in db.teams on r.id equals t2.id
                          where l.tracking_id == trackingID
                          select new { l.op_code, l.op_date, l.op_description, l.op_refer_code, l.op_refer_comments, t.team_name, l.id, t2.team_name });
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

So, I looked over here and there, and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978395/an-anonymous-type-cannot-have-multiple-properties-with-the-same-name), but I am unable to figure out how to apply the solution to my method. I googled for "EF naming types" and similar to try to understand what is being asked from me, but honestly I was unable to figure out by myself.

So, I *believe* the problem is because EF wants me to set a unique name to my db.team... which I thought I'd given it by calling it t2. This approach does work on SQL, but I do not understand how to apply the same to my method. I did find some clues such as `new{t2=t.id}` but different errors starting to pop-up in different places.

Help/Directions please?

Comment: The second sentence from that answer: _"You can fix that by giving explicit property names, for example: `new { u1 = m.UserId, u2 = u.UserId }`"_... That _is_ the solution. If that caused new errors, show them.

Comment: using `join t2 in db.teams on r.id equals new { t2=t2.id }` changes the error to the `join` "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect". I do get the point that the linked question is likely what I need, the problem is that I am unable to figure out what is being done and apply it

Comment: It's not the join part you need to alter, it's the `select new { ... }` part.

Comment: Yeah... I just realized after looking at @Ric reply... I don't know where I got lost on the other post, just applied it here and, of course, it worked.

Comment: No problem, happy we could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give names to properties in your projectction ie

`.Select(x => new { firstItem = x.y, secondItem = x.x });`

You can use this to get around your problem.

Or, as you are doing it:

`select new { firstItem = x.y, secondItem = x.x } .....`